# Bootstrap4: Displaying 3 columns in two rows on narrow screens

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I would like to create a pagination component that would look like this:

On a wide screen:

```
|                                                       | 
| [<<]                Page # 1 of 6                [>>] |
|                                                       |
```

On a narrow screen:

```
|                      |
|    Page # 1 of 6     | 
| [<<]            [>>] |
|                      |
```

I have tried the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 order-md-2 order-xs-1 text-center">
      blah blah blah [B]
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 order-md-1 order-xs-2 text-left">
      &laquo;&laquo;&laquo; [A]
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 order-md-3 order-xs-3 text-right">
      &raquo;&raquo;&raquo; [C]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/nonZero/pen/XZaxBR

But on a narrow screen I get this instead:

```
|                      |
|    Page # 1 of 6     | 
| [<<]                 |
|                 [>>] |
|                      |
```

(Edit: fixed `xs-12` and `xs-6` were mixed in the original post, but the question is still open.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are NO `col-xs-*` classes in Bootstrap 4 (anymore). They have been replaced with just `col-*`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 text-center">
            blah blah blah [B]
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 order-md-first">
            &laquo;&laquo;&laquo; [A]
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 text-right">
            &raquo;&raquo;&raquo; [C]
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(Notice: `text-left` is unnecessary because that's the default.)

Also, the use of the `order-first` class allows to do away with the `order-1` and `order-2` classes.

Comment: Thank you! replacing `col-xs-*` with `col-*` solved this - my IDE suggested  `col-xs` because I had another bootstrap css in one of my project's libraries. 
 I have edited your answer for brevity.

Comment: You can also remove `order-1` and `order-2` as they are not needed.

Comment: @Udi Oh, yes! When rushing to post my answer I sometimes forget the most obvious things! :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** - col-xs-* have been dropped in Bootstrap 4. Use col-* instead.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6  order-md-2 order-xs-1 text-center">
      blah blah blah [B]
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-6 order-md-1 order-xs-2 text-left">
      &laquo;&laquo;&laquo; [A]
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-6 order-md-3 order-xs-3 text-right">
      &raquo;&raquo;&raquo; [C]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PQKxOZ

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: @Udi Updated. The problem here is that its not fetching the xs media queries. I have added for now. This should help you.

Comment: `50%` is not a good solution. I would like to keep using flexbox.

Comment: For wxample. check window width exactly at width 544

Comment: Got it! col-xs-* has been removed in Bootstrap 4 with col-*.